# Would a join be better than this sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a table variable, which has been populated with the primary key of some Overpayments I am dealing with in a stored procedure. This table can have betweem ZERO and 10 rows in it.

For each 'OverpaymentID', I need to calculate the value of payments that have already been made to this debt. In order to do that, I use my temp table as the root, and then use a sub query to join the rows from other tables that I require, and sum the value in that sub query as seen below:

```
UPDATE op
SET op.PaymentsTotal = breakdown.amt
FROM @Overpayments op
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT op.OverpaymentID, SUM(da.Amount) AS amt
  FROM dbo.OverpaymentPlan op
  INNER JOIN dbo.OverpaymentPlanSchedule ops
  ON ops.OverpaymentPlanID = op.OverpaymentPlanID
  INNER JOIN dbo.PaymentAllocation pa
  ON pa.OverpaymentPlanScheduleID = ops.OverpaymentPlanScheduleID
  INNER JOIN dbo.DailyAllocation da
  ON da.PaymentAllocationID = pa.PaymentAllocationID
  GROUP BY op.OverpaymentID
) breakdown
ON breakdown.OverpaymentID = op.OverpaymentID
```

I'm worried that this might be inefficient. Am I right in saying that, because the sub query has no WHERE clause - it's going to sum up ALL values in all rows in my tables (These tables have millions of records), and then only select the few I need for my temp table?

The only issue with the 'JOIN' method, was when I tried to add a SUM, I got an error saying I can't use SUM, in an UPDATE.

OR, can SQL see the JOIN that I am doing to the sub query, and only get the relevent rows?

OR ... should I find a way to do this WITHOUT a sub query? I think it could be done with a join instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  The subquery will be completely evaluated because of the `group by` statement.  It is not necessarily true that a subquery would be optimized separately from the overall query, but in my experience, this is true for an aggregation.

One easy way to fix this is using `cross apply`:

```
UPDATE op2
    SET op.PaymentsTotal = breakdown.amt
    FROM @Overpayments op2 CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT op.OverpaymentID, SUM(da.Amount) AS amt
          FROM dbo.OverpaymentPlan op INNER JOIN
               dbo.OverpaymentPlanSchedule ops
               ON ops.OverpaymentPlanID = op.OverpaymentPlanID INNER JOIN
               dbo.PaymentAllocation pa
               ON pa.OverpaymentPlanScheduleID = ops.OverpaymentPlanScheduleID INNER JOIN
               dbo.DailyAllocation da
               ON da.PaymentAllocationID = pa.PaymentAllocationID
          WHERE op2.OverpaymentID = op.OverpaymentID
          GROUP BY op.OverpaymentID
         ) breakdown;
```

You could also use a correlated subquery for this.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon - Would it also be acceptable to add a join to my temp table within the sub query - thereby limiting the values in the sub query?

Comment: @Craig . . . Yes, that is a fine approach as well.